# Afterstack - Productivity tool for the Stack Exchange Network sites

Tags: app, website

[image: Afterstack Logo]

#### About:

Afterstack is a tool, for the Stack Exchange Network sites, that provides: integrated searching, answer saving, refined results and profile based suggestions.

Currently:

- 5 sites are supported: **Stack Overflow, Super User, Ask Ubuntu, Ask
  Different and Server Fault** (more to be added soon).
- Searching does not require a user profile, however, saving answers
  and receiving personalized suggestions requires **sign in by using
  either a Github or a Google account**. *User registration is not
  supported.*
- Only questions that **have been answered** are returned in the results.
  The **top 5 questions** are returned by default per every search (more
  options to be added soon)
- The **top 5 answers** per question are visible
- Each user profile can contain up to 50
  saved answers.

version: 0.1 beta

#### Screenshots

[image: Main Q/A Viewer]

[image: Search Related Saved Answers]

[image: User Profile]

#### Download / Install:

https://www.afterstack.io

#### Contact:

contact@afterstack.io

Comment: Suggestion: Afterstack is a tool<del>,</del> for the Stack Exchange Network **of Question & Answer web**sites, that provides<del>,</del> integrated searching, answer saving, refined results and profile based suggestions.

Comment: Also, why use GitHub/Google account(s) for sign in instead of associating with a user's SE account via Stack Exchange Authentication?

Comment: @3D1T0R thanks for suggestions! With regards your first comment I am currently implementing the introduction of Github issues also into the platform and as such this description most likely will become: **Afterstack simplifies the process of problem-solving for IT professionals by combining data from popular online communities such as Stack Overflow and Github within a unified user interface**... etc.  With regards authentication it is already on the roadmap to add SE auth and also user reg, but currently responsiveness, categories and Github issues are priorities.

Comment: Well, I was really interested in this, but if I have to use Google/Github to log in, I'm not.

Comment: @3D1T0R signup/signin is already on the roadmap for v2 as I mentioned in my previous comments. I will keep you posted. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 2):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

**The text box is super narrow! The site is unusable!**

Click for larger image:
[image]

Comment: That site currently uses a rather, um, unique styling.  You need a browser window of at least, about 1600 pixels. ;)

Comment: @sag Thank you for the feedback.  The site is not yet responsive (its just a prototype so far) and those kind of issues can be expected.  Besides the narrow text on the home page did you experience any functional issues?